# How to increase Java SOAP web service client performance in Linux

Tags: java, performance, optimization, soap

We are calling SOAP web service from Linux. We have created a jar file of the client application and calling from the shell script using 'java' command.
Through command line arguments we are passing input data.
The issue is that for every java call a new JVM process will be started which degrading the performance. Is there any better way to do this instead of calling a web service with 'java' command every time?

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to have your java application serve as middleware. By letting it run continuously, you won't incur startup performance penalties. You can make your calls through another program, written either in C/C++, a web front-end, or ruby/python.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Java JVM startup is slow.

There are two possible ways to address this:

- Try to make the JVM startup faster.
- Redesign your system to avoid multiple JVM starts.

One way to try to make the startup faster using AOT.  Java 9 introduced an experimental "ahead of time" (AOT) compilation feature with the goal of reducing startup and warmup overheads.  See https://www.baeldung.com/ahead-of-time-compilation and https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295 for more details.

Note that Java AOT is an experimental feature.  I've not seen any reports on how effective it is in real-world applications.

The other approach redesign your system so that the JVM doesn't need to start a JVM so often.  Here are some ways you could it:

- Redesign the SOAP API so that the SOAP requests do more work; e.g. instead of each request doing one task, create one that does a bundle of tasks.
- Redesign the Java application so that it performs a batch of SOAP requests.  For example, if your shell script is looping over a bunch of files and calling the Java app for each one, change it so that the app does the looping itself.
- Rearchitect the Java application into a long-running service that you can submit requests to using HTTP/HTTPS (e.g. with `curl`), by "dropping files into a directory", and so on.   There are many possible options here.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen C for the answer. I'll try curl.